# Why is String.split behaving like this?

Tags: java, regex, string

My code is

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String inputString = "#..#...##";

        String[] abc = inputString.trim().split("#+");

        for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(abc[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(abc.length);

    }
}
```

The output abc  is an array of length 3. 
with abc[0] being an empty string. The other two elements in abc are .. and ...

If my inputString is "..##...". I don't get a empty string in the array returned by split function.  The input String doesn't have trailing whitespace in both cases.

Can soemone explain me why do I get a extra space in the code shown above?

Comment: It's split to "", "..", "..." if my guess is correct.

Comment: You have an empty string before the first delimiter, so an empty string is returned.  Empty strings at the end are not returned, unless you supply an extra argument to split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get an extra space, you get the empty string (with length 0). It says so in the javadoc:

```
 * <p> When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this
 * string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning
 * of the resulting array. A zero-width match at the beginning however
 * never produces such empty leading substring
```

Comment: Could you provide the link to java doc?

Comment: Sure, first result: [java.lang.String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-                                                                   Posting the proper link. It's there in Java 8 SDK

Answer (score 0):

When you split by `#+` and first character of input string is `#` then input is split at beginning itself and what you get is an empty string as first element of string. It is due to the fact that left hand side of first `#` is just anchor `^` which will give an empty string only in the resulting array.

Comment: There's also `$` in the end.

Comment: And how is that relevant to the answer? Any matching delimiter just causes LHS token into resulting array.

Comment: It's not completely true, `"o".split("o", 2)` gives an array with two empty strings. I.e. `^(match)$` gives empty strings on both sides of the match.

Comment: That is due to your 2nd parameter only.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

And [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you say .split to a String, it splits the String n number of times that condition is met.

So when you say

```
String inputString = "#..#...##";
```

and your condition for spliting is `#` and since the value before the first occurrence of `#` is `empty`, `abc[0]` will hold `empty`. Therefore count of abc will  return 3 because abc[0]=nothing(empty string), abc[1]=.. abc[2]=...